# Why did Italy wait 45 days to exit WWII after the fall of Mussolini?

Tags: world-war-two, italy, mussolini

Benito Mussolini was deposed on the 25 of July 1943. From reading the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_the_Fascist_regime_in_Italy), it seems that the main reason is that the king and high-rank officials understood the war was lost. The new government of Badoglio continued the war, waiting till the 3 of September to sign an armistice with the Allies (announced to the population on the 8 of September). This gave Nazi Germany plenty of time to send more divisions into Italy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Achse), making the war last till the end of April 1945.
The question is then: why did the new government take so long to sign an armistice? Since the reason for the deposition seems to end the war, why didn't they sign an armistice immediately?

Comment: Because those who toppled Mussolini were fascist themselves (Grandi and others), and Italy could not just "exit" the war. They wanted to negotiate peace terms and save their own skins (plus some pieces of power if possible). This goes especially for Victor Emmanuel III who was afraid (rightly) that monarchy would be abolished. Of course, there was also a fear what would Germans and their loyalist do, because there were no Allied troops on Italian mainland as yet (only on Sicily) .

Comment: I thought that Italy didn't 'exit World War II', in 1943, but that they switched sides and joined the allies as a 'co-belligerent'. Except for the Republic of Salò of course.